# What is the difference between Server and Embedded Intel server processors

Tags: cpu

I am in the process of building a server that will run SQL Server 2012 and was looking for a processor. While doing my research I have found Intel processors on their page being grouped in two categories [Server and Embedded](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/78583/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-v3-Family#@Embedded). Does it mean that embedded CPUs are soldered into motherboard or is it something else?

**What is the difference between Server and Embedded Intel server processors?**

Comment: if you hover over an embedded chips "Embedded Options Available", you see this text: "Embedded Options Available indicates products that offer extended purchase availability for intelligent systems and embedded solutions. Product certification and use condition applications can be found in the Production Release Qualification (PRQ) report. See your Intel representative for details." 

I have confirmed that at least some of the embedded chips come in removable form factors like FCLGA2011, so no, it does not imply that they are soldered in.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hi Frank, could you post it as an answer please, so I could accept it. Although this raises a different question  What is Production Release Qualification (PRQ) and Intelligent systems :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copied from a comment by @FrankThomas:**

if you hover over an embedded chips "Embedded Options Available", you see this text:

> "Embedded Options Available indicates products that offer extended purchase availability for intelligent systems and embedded solutions. Product certification and use condition applications can be found in the Production Release Qualification (PRQ) report. See your Intel representative for details."

I have confirmed that at least some of the embedded chips come in removable form factors like FCLGA2011, so no, it does not imply that they are soldered in.